# How to remove keycloak realm role for user using python

Tags: python, realm, keycloak

I am trying to add and remove realm role for a user in keycloak using python.

For adding a realm role to user I am using following function

```
keycloak_admin.assign_realm_roles(user_id=user_keycloak_id,
                                          client_id=keycloak_admin.client_id,
                                          roles={'id': role_id, "name": role_name})
```

But to remove role for a user I didn't get any function.

Even if its API to delete role for user, I want to know how to use it in python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could find it looks like you're using [this git repository](https://github.com/marcospereirampj/python-keycloak).  And, [here](https://github.com/marcospereirampj/python-keycloak/blob/4315d90d0be73139dc4f839cc9ce7e940cc3d4d3/keycloak/keycloak_admin.py#L925) is the method you're calling now.  But there isn't a delete/remove.

Keycloak does provide this as an API so your best bet would be to have your own delete.  Something like this (warning - untested!!):

```
def remove_realm_roles(self, user_id, client_id, roles):
    """
    Removes realm roles to a user
    :param user_id: id of user
    :param client_id: id of client containing role (not client-id)
    :param roles: roles list or role (use RoleRepresentation)
    :return Keycloak server response
    """

    payload = roles if isinstance(roles, list) else [roles]
    params_path = {"realm-name": self.realm_name, "id": user_id}
    data_raw = self.raw_delete(URL_ADMIN_USER_REALM_ROLES.format(**params_path),
                             data=json.dumps(payload))
    return raise_error_from_response(data_raw, KeycloakGetError, expected_code=204)
```

The only change to the code from the git repository is that this is using `raw_delete` instead of `raw_post`.  The Keycloak Admin REST API docs show that it's taking the exact same parameters so it's just a matter of changing the HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin, raise_error_from_response, 
  KeycloakGetError, URL_ADMIN_USER_REALM_ROLES


def remove_role(role_name, role_id, realm_name, user_id, admin_token):
    params_path = {"realm-name": realm_name, "id": user_id}
    head = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(admin_token)}
    url = URL_ADMIN_USER_REALM_ROLES.format(**params_path)
    data = [{"clientRole": False, "composite": False, "containerId": realm_name, "id": role_id, "name": role_name}]
    data_raw = KeycloakAdmin.raw_delete(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=head)
    return raise_error_from_response(data_raw, KeycloakGetError)
```